# How to set default value to column in ormlite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I am new to ormlite and i want to set default value for some fields like

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, canBeNull = false)
int id;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
String user_type;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
String username;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
String password;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
int id_color;
```

I have to set the default value for the username field.  How do I do this?  Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have to set the default value for the username field. How do I do this?

I've spent a lot of time on the [ORMLite documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html).  You should always start there.  If you go to the documentation index, and look up [default value](http://ormlite.com/docs/default-value) it would show you that there is a `defaultValue` field in `@DatabaseField` annotation.  Here are the [javadocs for that field](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#defaultValue%28%29).

Something like the following should work:

```
@DatabaseField(defaultValue = "unknownName", canBeNull = true)
String username;
```

Comment: How should I handle the `defaultValue` for `boolean`?  I know that this is stored as an `int` in `SQLite`, but neither `defaultValue="1"` nor `defaultValue="true"` seemed to work.  I can set it using the `setter` before I `create`, but I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: @mattblang try changing boolean to Boolean

Answer (score 1):

However, when you have to initialize a Date field to current date, using default value is delecate.

So in constructor of your domain class (let be Person), you should initialize this field as following :

```
public Person(String user_type,...,Date enrollement){
    this.user_type=user_type; 
    //....
    // or Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    this.enrollement = (enrollement == null ) ? new Date() : enrollement;
}
```